# How to hide backgrid column?

Tags: backgrid

Hi friends. I'm using `backgrid` in my project. I want to hide Id column from `backgrid`. Here is my code.

```
var columns = [
{ name: "id", label: "Id", cell: "integer", editable: false },
{ name: "payment_date", label: "Payment Date", cell: "date" ,editable: false },
{ name: "number_of_task", label: "Total Task", cell: "integer" ,editable: false },
{ name: "amount", label: "Amount", cell: "integer" ,editable: false }
];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add a `renderable: false` attribute.  See renderable here http://wyuenho.github.io/backgrid/api/index.html#!/api/Backgrid.Column

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the column definition. You don't need a column definition for each addribute in your data; you only need the column definition of attributes you want visible in the table.

```
var columns = [
    { name: "payment_date", label: "Payment Date", cell: "date" ,editable: false },
    { name: "number_of_task", label: "Total Task", cell: "integer" ,editable: false },
    { name: "amount", label: "Amount", cell: "integer" ,editable: false }];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I need Id column as a hidden field.So i need to hide that not remove.Any suggestion might be helpful.Thanks

Comment: Just curious, when you mean hidden, do you mean so that it can be toggled as visible or not? In which case, you're right, the column definition is necessary.

Comment: Actually Id field is my required field for performing update/delete operations so i just want to hide/invisible it including Id tr and all its tds.

Comment: problem is solved by Mark add a renderable: false attribute. See renderable here http://wyuenho.github.io/backgrid/api/index.html#!/api/Backgrid.Column

Comment: I needed to hide a column so I could still use it to sort the table by.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute renderable:false didn't work for me hence used below as workaround

```
var HideCell = Backgrid.HideCell = Backgrid.Cell.extend({
    /** @property */
    className: "hide-cell",

    initialize: function () {
        Backgrid.Cell.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.hide();
        return this;
    }
});
```

use in column as cell "hide"

```
var columns = [
    { name: "id", label: "Id", cell: HideCell, editable: false }
];
```